# Get all the files that match pattern in file name anywhere in unix/linux directories/subdirectories

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I have 100s of main directories where I have multiple subdirectories in each main directory and a few subdirectories within each subdirectory. I want to get all the files that match pattern in file name `mypattern` anywhere in any of those directories/subdirectories. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  This really isn't a programming question, though...

```
 find . -regex '.*regex_here.*'
```

Have a look at `man find`.

Comment: The -print action expression as in `find . -regex '...'  -print` used to be required, but I notice even POSIX has it now as an implicit default now (like you show). I still use it by habit. Dash -regex isn't POSIX, but cool. I didn't know it existed (BSD too apparently). Very nice.

Answer (score 4):

```
  find <root directory> -name *pattern*
```

ex: `find . -name *nix*`